# error in using vertex.setProperties() function for orientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

The method setProperties(HashMap) is undefined for the type 
Vertex.
[image: the header files included]

[image: here is the code]

[image: Error Shown]

Comment: You're calling a method that isn't present in the (tinkerpop) Vertex interface.

Comment: I got the fix . Need to typecast v to orientvertex ,                                                              proper usage  = ((OrientVertex) v).setProperties(properties);